# Getting Cordova error on Xcode 7 build for Facebook Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova, bitcode

I updated to XCode 7 today. As suggested in the [Cordova Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) I cloned the git repo and am installing the plugin from there. Before the update to XCode 7 I had no problems building. Now I am getting the below error.

Error:

`ld: 'App/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLikeButtonBackgroundSelectedPNG.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Any thoughts?

I tried removing and re-adding the ios platform with no luck.

Also this builds fine to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable bitcode (next cordova ios release will come with bitcode disabled)
You can do that on the xcode project, open the `.xcodeproj` on yourProject/platforms/ios/, and on the project build settings search for `ENABLE_BITCODE` and set it to `NO`

Or you can go to /platforms/ios/cordova and add this line on the build.xcconfig

```
ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
```

Comment: That line is already in my /platforms/ios/cordova build.xconfig file, and Xcode ignored it. This answer helped me instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636622/error-after-updating-to-xcode-7/32710815#32710815 i.e., going into "Build Settings" in Xcode and manually setting Build Settings>All>Build Options>Enable Bitcode = NO

Comment: I gave two options, the first one is the one you link, the second one only works if you run from the cli.