# missing required architecture x86_64 in ...libMumbleKit.a (3 slices)

Tags: ios, xcode, x86-64

I am trying to include MumbleKit as a library instead of having to compile it each time by following the suggestion of a member of this forum. Yet when I try to compile on the simulator I get:

> missing required architecture x86_64 in …libMumbleKit.a (3 slices)

I think I added all the necessary versions to MumbleKit before generating the library:

> arm64 armv7 armv7s armv7k arm7s x86_64 i386

notwithstanding, when I execute:

> lipo -info libMumbleKit.a

I get:

> Architectures in the fat file: libMumbleKit.a are: armv7 armv7s arm64

as well as configuring Build Active Architecture to NO.
I generated the library for MumbleKit both using the Generic iOS device and a iOS 9 physical device.

When I try to archive using the Generic iOS Device option after having extracted the Mumble library in the same way, I instead get error:

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/fbartolom/Documents/cocoa
>   applications/inArrivoHD/MumbleKit/libMumbleKit.a(CryptState.o)' was
>   built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode
>   must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture
>   armv7

Same when using my physical device after also generating the library in the correspondent way:

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/fbartolom/Documents/cocoa
>   applications/inArrivoHD/MumbleKit/libMumbleKit.a(CryptState.o)' was
>   built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode
>   must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture
>   arm64

And finally the installation on my iOS 9 iPhone 6S went fine with just the same contents in the warning:

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/fbartolom/Documents/cocoa
>   applications/inArrivoHD/MumbleKit/libMumbleKit.a(CryptState.o)' was
>   built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode
>   must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture
>   arm64

CryptState.cpp if a c++ file in the library.

Comment: Have you try Build Active Architecture Only to No.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I aborted the attempt. There must be something faulty in the original mumble kit project not allowing to import its library into another project, or I do not know how to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check architectures it has with *lipo* tool. Open terminal, navigate to folder where your library is and do:

lipo -info yourlib.a

If you don't have x86_64, than you should find/compile lib that will have it.

x86_64 is an architecture for Simulator, not for generic iOS device.

Comment: I have also edited my request providing the result of my new tests.

Comment: In fact this is the result of the command:
Architectures in the fat file: libMumbleKit.a are: armv7 armv7s arm64
Why the architecture I inserted in the library did not get introduced in the fat file?

Comment: I think, you need to compile separate lib for simulator purposes. There must be option for this, I guess.

Comment: I had no problems of the kind when I generate the PLCrashReporter framework, and I frankly ignore how to do it. At any rate I am not able to archive in either way, and that is the major problem.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the suggestion at:

[Xcode 7 'CrashReporter does not contain bitcode' linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525916/xcode-7-crashreporter-does-not-contain-bitcode-linker-error)

by adding option *-fembed-bitcode* to the other linker flags field. And now the problem has moved to a c file: band.c, notwithstanding of course I have added this option for the c and c++ files.

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/fbartolom/Documents/cocoa
>   applications/inArrivoHD/MumbleKit/libMumbleKit.a(bands.o)' was built
>   without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must
>   be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture
>   arm64

What might be still missing?